# Is it possible to print Javadoc in console? Or export Javadoc contents to a string?

Tags: java, console, javadoc

When you write your java code, you also write corresponding Javadoc (especially those that are right above each method). I am wondering if there is a way to get the Javadoc contents print out in the console.

My reason for doing this is that I don't want to write help documentation twice. I've already written a good amount of information in my Javadoc, and I am really reluctant to write the same thing separately in another place.

I don't think I've found anything on Google that is related to this question, but I wonder if anyone knows how to do so.

I am thinking use this approach: use a scanner and read my java source code, and when it reads  /**, it will start adding contents followed up to a string, and will stop adding content if it sees a */.  Do you think this will be a good approach to implement? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

There's the javadoc tool which will generate a website from you javadoc comments on the source code. It is included in your JDK's bin folder.

Comment: Yes, that's for sure. However, I am writing a command line program, and I wish users could quickly get help contents without even opening a web browser. It should be just like Python or R's help options. I just really wonder if I have to write a separate documentation for the entire program, especially when I put good amount of information in my javadoc.

Comment: Well you can't get the javadoc from the source on runtime, but you could use Doclet with javadoc to extract that information to a file

Answer (score 0):

There is an API for writing your own Doclet to process the Javadoc comments into the form you need. See the [Doclet Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html)